# Print issue with randint in python

Tags: python, random

So I have the following code:

```
from random import *  
def main():  
    die1 = randint(1,6)  
    die2 = randint(1,6)     
    dietotal = die1 + die2  
    print dietotal  
main()
```

Now I am expecting a random integer that is the summation of die1 and die2. What I get, however, is a syntax error which highlights dietotal in the print statement. All randint does is return a random integer so I shouldn't have a problem here. Why am I getting this syntax error?

Comment: whats up with those stars? check your indentation `python -tt myscript.py`

Comment: Like @JoranBeasley said. Your code won't even run with those asterisks.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I guess the stars were intended to markup the code block.

Comment: I assumed as much ... but if not that would certainly be an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you're using Python 3, and that's a Python 2 style print statement.  For example:

```
localhost-2:coding $ python3 dierand.py
  File "dierand.py", line 7
    print dietotal
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but

```
localhost-2:coding $ python2.7 dierand.py
10
```

In Python 3, `print` is a function, not a statement, and so you need parentheses:

```
print(dietotal)
```